# matching an array with another array

Tags: c#

i'm looking for an array matching method.

here i have two arrays as the code shows

```
char[] normalText = new char[26] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char[] parsedText = new char[26] {'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ...};
```

and, i want to match them so, if i write "abc" in the program it will turn into "bcd"
and, i've made a text parser method like this:

```
        parsing = input.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in parsing)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

but, i don't know what kind of query should i do to match them after the foreach statement. if you know how to match this in code, please post here, it would be VERY2 APPRECIATED

Comment: you have two arrays called `normalText` ?

Comment: Do you want to check if they are equal or do you want to see if one is a subset of the other?

Comment: Why do you declare two `normalText` arrays, how are they related to each other? What's the rule to turn the input of "abc" into "bcd"? I'm afraid your question is currently not very clear.

Comment: a job for `Dictionary`?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter  It looks like he wants to use the arrays to define a mapping by index.  ie : `arr1[1] = 'a'` therefore `return arr2[1]` (= 'b')

Comment: @cfedermann no, this is not a homework

Answer (score 2):

I'd use something like this:

```
var input = "abc";
var parsing = input.ToCharArray();
var result = new StringBuilder();
var offset = (int)'a';
foreach (var c in parsing) {
    var x = c - offset;
    result.Append(parsedText[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use these to make for a 1:1 translation.

The best (ie:most extensible) way to do this is probably with a dictionary :

```
Dictionary<char, char> dictionary = new Dictionary<char, char>();
dictionary.Add('a', 'b');
dictionary.Add('b', 'c');
dictionary.Add('c', 'd');
//... etc (can do this programmatically, also
```

then :

```
char newValue = dictionary['a'];
Console.WriteLine(newValue.ToString()); // "b"
```

and so on.  Using a dictionary you get all the power of lists, as well, which can be immensely handy depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  what you want. You can use `Array.IndexOf(oldText, s)` to get index of character in old array and then get value in new array by that index.

```
string input="abc";
char[] oldText = new char[26] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char[] newText = new char[26] { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','a'};

char[] array = input.ToCharArray();
StringBuilder output= new StringBuilder();
foreach(char s in array)
{
  output.Append(newText[Array.IndexOf(oldText, s)]);
}

Console.WriteLine(output.ToString()); // "bcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, now format it to a way best suited to you.

```
char[] normalText = new char[26] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char[] dictionary = new char[26] {'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y' };    

parsing = input.ToCharArray();  
foreach (char c in parsing)
        {
           if(index(c,normalText)<= dictionary.Length) 
               Console.WriteLine(dictionary[index(c,normalText)]);
        }

int index(char lookFor, char[] lookIn) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lookIn.Length; i++)
            {
                if (lookIn[i] == lookFor)
                    return i;
            }
        return -1;
    }
```